# iOS Drawing PDFs with UIGraphics: how to set document title?

Tags: ios, pdf, uigraphicscontext

I'm drawing a PDF using `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData` and it's working fine except that the document is always Untitled. Is there a way to set the title metadata when using UIGraphics, or do I need to rewrite using `CGPDFDocument`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this link [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1623931-uigraphicsbeginpdfcontexttodata).

The section on documentInfo refers to a dictionary you can pass in. In that dictionary, it contains a key for a title.

[Dictionary information](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgcontext/1666607-auxiliary_dictionary_keys).

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'd read that before but couldn't find my way through the link path to get the dictionary keys!